# I want to use a Discord Role as requirement for a Command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im coding a Discord bot in Python, and i want to make a Command which requires a Role. Is there a way to use a role as requirement in a if statement?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(role='Role name')
    async def command(ctx):
```

and yea
or if it doesn't work you need to put the `@commands.has_role(role='Role name')` above `@client.command()`
if you don't get it you can read the documentation

or you can do `@commands.has_permission(kind of permission=True/False)` for it as well role means the **NEED** the *role* and permission means they also need the permission but you need to have a **discord role permission** or else it would send it doesn't know the kind of permission

Answer (score 1):

I've done exactly that in a bot I've created recently, I set up my commands as JSON configs with data including syntax, description, and allowed roles. The bot uses DiscordJS, but I'm sure you can use the same principles for a Python bot:

```
if (cmd.allowedRoles.includes('everyone') || message.member.roles.cache.some(role => cmd.allowedRoles.includes(role.name.toLowerCase())))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(**permission needed**=True)
```

Which will only allow people with certain permissions to be allowed to do the command (Error messages option). Or if you want only people with a role you can use
`if message.author.role.id == **role id**:`
or
`if ctx.message.author.role.id == **role id**:`. Here is an example code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    link = ["https://"]
    for word in link:
        if message.content.count(word) > 0:
            if message.author.role.id == 706694479847096381:
                return
            else:
                print(f'{message.author}({message.author.id}) Sent an link')
                await message.delete()
```

This code allows the bot to ignore people with that role when they send a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use argparse and create a required argument called role. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html#required).